# Html Table - maximize size of font in cells

Tags: jquery, html-table

I would appreciate some help or suggestions with my current project.

I have a simple webpage with an html form where a database is queried and the results return various rows and columns into a table.

What I need the table to do is maximize the size of text in the table cells. The tables CELL size should be even, but the text in the cell be as large as possible.

I've tried [jQuery BigText](http://jsfiddle.net/zachleat/WzN6d/) and [jTextFill](http://jsfiddle.net/2btyN/), but they both seem to depend on a fixed width/height. As each database query returns various number of rows / columns, I can't set a fixed width/height as it would not maximize the screen with a small table result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finished this. It uses jQuery mostly for convenience/compatibility. Turns your HTML table into an expanding width font table.

http://jsfiddle.net/fnbrb/1/

Here it is after some more fiddling. Maybe this works better:
http://jsfiddle.net/xXHLc/11/

Here is the JS but it requires a few styles as well:

```
    jQuery("#expandable-font-table TD").each(function()
    {
        // need to set up the DIVs and TDs first
        var jTd = jQuery(this);
        var jDiv = jTd.find("DIV");
        jDiv.width(jTd.width()+"px"); //set the DIV's width to it's parent TD
        jTd.width(jTd.width()+"px"); //set the width of the TD so the table doesn't get confused
    });

    jQuery("#expandable-font-table TD DIV").each(function()
    {
        // get each DIV in the table and maximize it's font size
        var jDiv = jQuery(this);
        this.style.visibility="hidden"; // hide while resizing
        var fontSize = jDiv.css("font-size"); // current default font size
        fontSize = fontSize.substring(0,fontSize.length-2);
        // loop while DIV is still within it's original width
        while(this.scrollWidth <= this.clientWidth)
        {
            fontSize++;
            this.style.fontSize = fontSize+"px";
        }
        this.style.fontSize = (fontSize-1)+"px";
        this.style.visibility="visible";        
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew,  This is actually very close to what I´m looking for. But for some reason the effect is broken if I set the table width some value (100% is prefered). Then the script only effects the first column and the font size decreases with each column

Comment: Updated just now. It even preserves vertical-align on the table cells now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there any font metrics functions in HTML/Javascript.  In some UI libraries you can use them to measure a string at different font sizes before rendering it.  Without that, you could resort to something like the code below, but it is kind of a hack.  Maybe someone will know a better way.

This code test renders the strings, to look at their `offsetWidth`, and then renders them again, bumping their font sizes until they are about the same width as the largest string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
function init() {
    var exampleData = [
       ["one", "this is longest cell", "apple"],
       ["banana", "peach", "kiwi"],
       ["AB", "yabba", "foo bar baz"]
                       ];
    var ncols = 3;
    var tab = document.getElementById('tab');
    var testArea = document.getElementById('testArea');

    // First, loop through the cells and find the biggest one
    var maxWidth = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<exampleData.length; i++) {
        var rowData = exampleData[i];
        for (var j=0; j<ncols; j++) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = rowData[j];
            testArea.appendChild(span);
            if (maxWidth < span.offsetWidth)
                maxWidth = span.offsetWidth;
            testArea.removeChild(span);
        }
    }
    // now, add them to the table, bumping the font so the span is as 
    // wide as maxWidth
    for (var i=0; i<exampleData.length; i++) {
        var rowData = exampleData[i];
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j=0; j<ncols; j++) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = rowData[j];
            testArea.appendChild(span);
            /* Adjust style to get close to max size: */
            var fs = 10;
            span.style.fontSize = fs + "px";
            while (span.offsetWidth < maxWidth) {
                fs += 1;
                span.style.fontSize = fs + "px"; 
            }
            // console.log(span.style.fontSize + " -> " + span.offsetWidth);            
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            row.appendChild(td);
            td.appendChild(span);
        }
        tab.appendChild(row);       
    }


}    
  </script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
<table id='tab'>
</table>
<div id='testArea' style='visibility:hidden'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Rob N,  This solution works very well and does  what I need. I just need to find the best way to write the mysql query results to the script variable (examleData in you suggested solution)

Comment: I guess that's another question, but it would depend on how your app is working.  I think a good way is to use a JSON library.  You would create the list in whatever server-side language you have and then turn it to a JSON string, which you then either render into the page when the page is created in PHP/JSP/etc, or return as the result of an asynchronous query.

Comment: If this is an answer, can you accept it?  If not, is there something I can fix?